# Cool Styling for dropdown list in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

I wonder if we can give the default dropdownlist a cool and classy look using css/styling. I do not want to use jquery/jscript as I am not familiar with these.
Can it be done using css/html styling ?

```
I want it to look something like this :
```

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Atleast some links. examples can help me, where I can pick some codes to help myself.

Comment: @HiteshGawhade Even if you don't know jQuery, you can find some free libraries with controls that do what you need.

Comment: @Hitesh Gawhade added you some script samples.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure you can.

I recommend checking out http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

It's really just a mix of your standard commands: height, width, background, color, border. All put together to make it prettier. I'm not sure about offsetting it like in your example 2, but example 1 is easy.